# how do you fix a background image not loading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML:

```
`<div class="food-imagesM imagecontainer">
<!--Page info decoration etc.-->
</div>`
```

CSS:

```
`.food-imagesM.imagecontainer{
    background-image: url("/Images/Caribbean-food-Menu.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 100px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-bottom: absolute;
 }`
```

When I open up my program in chrome everything shows up but the background image doesn't show up I have linked everything correctly but sometimes my background image doesn't show up... How do i fix this? I have sevearal image containers but they dont have the same image.

Answer (score 2):

```
`.food-imagesH.imagecontainer{
    background-image: url("/Images/Caribbean-food-Menu.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 100px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-bottom: absolute;
 }`
```

Looks like you are trying to select both the classes to add CSS.
If that is correct, your class name in CSS is incorrect.
change food-imagesM to food-imagesH

Comment: This is a more appropriate answer, because maybe not all `imagecontainer`s need to have the food menu background.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is not right.
just use: `.imagecontainer`.

```
.imagecontainer{
    background-image: url("/Images/Caribbean-food-Menu.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 100px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-bottom: absolute;
 }
```

Comment: or `.food-imagesH.imagecontainer`, the issue is that OP has `M` instead of `H` in your CSS.

Comment: padding-bottom : absolute ??

Answer (score -1):

Change food-imagesM whit food-imagesH 
Other than this you have to add width and height to the class.
If you don't add width and height or content inside the div its size should be 0*0.

Comment: Oh yh sorry i have already changed the food-imagesH to food-imagesM as well as there is content inside the div but it just doesnt show the image.